# IE8 compatibility problem

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

Hello i have this pager added with success on Firefox but not visible in IE8.
Please take a look with Firefox first and then with IE8 at : http://www.poshsunglasses.net/Chanel-sunglasses.asp
Any idea? is driving me crazy ...

Thank you

Comment: "pager added with success" ? huh? can you be more specific on the location of this element?

Comment: is created dinamically from the js file .. i use the pager from :http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/paginate-anything-with-jquery-new-plus-tutorial/

Comment: to be more exact from here : http://poshsunglasses.net/js/jquery_paginate.js and is loaded by the                   $(function(){
              $("TABLE#tableOne").paginate({ limit: 3, content: 'TR' });

               
          });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validate the html, then check back. Most IE troubles begin and end with invalid markup.

http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.poshsunglasses.net%2FChanel-sunglasses.asp